# How can I combine n-number of boolean indexes to filter Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

Pandas boolean indexes are commonly combined with [logical operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
vdf = (df1['status'] == 'DENIED') | (df1['status'] == 'VOIDED') | (df1['void?'] == True)
```

I'm processing various DF tables. A table may have zero or many columns which I want to filter. When I say 'filter', I mean drop rows where a condition is true. If a transaction is voided, I want to drop it. If a transaction matches a specific category, I want to drop it.

How can I combine n-boolean indexes?

```
table = [('2019-01-01', 10.00, False, 'CAPTURED'),
         ('2019-01-04', 10.00, False, 'CAPTURED'),
         ('2019-01-05', 10.00, False, 'DENIED'),
         ('2019-01-06', 10.00, True, 'VOIDED'),
cols = ['date', 'amount', 'void?', 'status']
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table, columns=cols)

filter_headers = ['void?', 'status']
status_vals = ['VOIDED', 'DENIED']

try:
    if filter_headers:
        vdfs = []
        for fcol in filter_headers:
            if df1[fcol].dtype == 'bool':
                vdfs.append(df1[fcol] == True)
            elif df1[fcol].dtype == 'object':
                vdfs.append(df1[fcol].isin(status_vals))
            else:
                print("Unhandled type.")
        # Obviously wrong...
        df2 = df1[~sum(vdfs)]
    else:
        df2 = df1
except Exception as e:
    print("(%s) Filter Headers produced no results." % e)
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `sum`, you can use [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) with axis=0 such as:

```
import numpy as np
# mostly all your code except this line df2 = df1[~sum(vdfs)] that you replace by
df2 = df1[~np.any(vdfs, axis=0)]
```

In your example, the result for `df2` is then

```
         date  amount  void?    status
0  2019-01-01    10.0  False  CAPTURED
1  2019-01-04    10.0  False  CAPTURED
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, `DataFrame.loc` is what you are looking for. It selects rows where the index is `True`:

```
bindex = [not v and s not in status_vals for v, s in zip(df1['void?'], df1['status'])]
df2 = df1.loc[bindex]
```

`bindex` is a list of boolean, length equal to the number of rows in your dataframe. Is `False` if `df1['void?']` is `True` and `df1['status']` is not inside `status_val`. These two lines replace all your `try` `except` block.
Using de Morgan laws, `bindex` can also be rewritten as:

```
bindex = [not (v or s in status_vals) for v, s in zip(df1['void?'], df1['status'])]
```

Using the sample dataframe you posted, the result `df2` is:

```
         date  amount  void?    status
0  2019-01-01    10.0  False  CAPTURED
1  2019-01-04    10.0  False  CAPTURED
```